# Why are my qrcodes coming up green and why are the import functions not working?

Tags: python

[Screenshot of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fzo2.png)

Im new to python and not sure what is goin on this is the third attempt at creating a qr code generator, I am using visual studio code. I have been watching [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdy3nh1tn6I). Im not sure what's going on.

I have been trying to create a qr code and nothing is happening?

Comment: The "import code not working" image shows it waiting at the prompt for you to enter your input, before then running your `generate_qrcode` function. Did it not work after you gave it input?

Comment: you might not have installed python correctly with vscode. Can you tell what are the errors?

Comment: I think it is working i just dont know where to find the qr code?

Answer (score 0):

The "import code not working" image shows it waiting at the prompt for you to enter your input, before then running your `generate_qrcode` function.

In the tutorial video you're following, when they add `"Enter your url: "` in the `input(...)` -- that's not an instruction to you as the person following the tutorial for you to put the url you want to make a qr code for in the string that goes into that `input(...)`, it's a prompt that will be displayed to the person running it in the cli. See [the screen cap at this moment](https://youtu.be/pdy3nh1tn6I?t=4406), they've run it and demonstrated typing in `https://www.youtube.com/their_channel`, then pressed enter to pass their input to the `input(...)`.

All you should need to do is actually type your input in and press enter.